# Targeting tabs on page with direct URL link breaks URL on tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, url-rewriting, tabs

I'm trying to create a tabbed area within my page. The tabs navigate hidden areas with out leaving the page. I also want to be able to link to an area with in the page. It's working except when you click the menu as well as revealing the hidden area it's rewriting the URL with only the tab extension and therefor breaking the link of the URL. So someone trying to share the link would not know the format..

I'm using this code https://css-tricks.com/examples/OrganicTabsReplaceState which I see no problem with.

You can see a live demo with my issue here: http://bit.ly/1IP1ST4

Clicking the tab is removing:
/products/eurorack-modules/waveform-modifiers/reactive-shaper/

And replacing it with ?tab=mytabname

It should be simply adding it. I'm struggling to work out why..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of organictabs.jquery.js got it working in the end seemed to be an issue with the way it treated the URL.. Maybe this will help someone else.

```
// IIFE
(function($) {

    // Define Plugin
$.organicTabs = function(el, options) {

        // JavaScript native version of this
    var base = this;

    // jQuery version of this
    base.$el = $(el);

    // Navigation for current selector passed to plugin
    base.$nav = base.$el.find(".nav");

    // Returns the fragment identifier of the given URL
    function getFragmentIdentifier(url) {
        if(url && url.match && url.match(/#(.*)/)) {
            return RegExp.$1;
        }
    }

    // Remove the query string from the url
    function noQueryString(url) {
        if(url && url.match && url.match(/^([^\?]*)\??/)) {
            return RegExp.$1;
        }
    }

    // Runs once when plugin called       
    base.init = function() {

            // Pull in arguments
        base.options = $.extend({},$.organicTabs.defaultOptions, options);

        // Accessible hiding fix (hmmm, re-look at this, screen readers still run JS)
        $(".hide").css({
            "position": "relative",
            "top": 0,
            "left": 0,
            "display": "none"
        }); 

        // When navigation tab is clicked...
        base.$nav.delegate("a", "click", function(e) {

                // no hash links
                e.preventDefault();

            // Figure out current list via CSS class
            var curList = getFragmentIdentifier(base.$el.find("a.current").attr("href")),
            // List moving to
                $newList = $(this),

            // Figure out ID of new list
                listID = getFragmentIdentifier($newList.attr("href")),

            // Set outer wrapper height to (static) height of current inner list
                $allListWrap = base.$el.find(".list-wrap"),
                curListHeight = $allListWrap.height();
                    $allListWrap.height(curListHeight);


            if ((listID != curList) && ( base.$el.find(":animated").length == 0)) {
                // Fade out current list
                base.$el.find("#"+curList).fadeOut(base.options.speed, function() {

                    // Fade in new list on callback
                    base.$el.find("#"+listID).fadeIn(base.options.speed);

                    // Adjust outer wrapper to fit new list snuggly
                    var newHeight = base.$el.find("#"+listID).height();
                    $allListWrap.animate({
                        height: newHeight
                    }, base.options.speed);

                    // Remove highlighting - Add to just-clicked tab
                    base.$el.find(".nav li a").removeClass("current");
                    $newList.addClass("current");

                                            // Change window location to add URL params
                                            if (window.history && history.pushState) {
                                              // NOTE: doesn't take into account existing params
                                                history.replaceState("", "", noQueryString(window.location.href) + "?" + base.options.param + "=" + listID);
                                            }    
                });

            }   

        });

        var queryString = {};
                    window.location.href.replace(
                        new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
                        function($0, $1, $2, $3) { queryString[$1] = $3; }
                    );

        if (queryString[base.options.param]) {

            var tab = $("a[href='#" + queryString[base.options.param] + "']");

                        tab
                            .closest(".nav")
                            .find("a")
                            .removeClass("current")
                            .end()
                            .next(".list-wrap")
                            .find("ul")
                            .hide();
                        tab.addClass("current");
                        $("#" + queryString[base.options.param]).show();

                };            

    };
    base.init();
};

    $.organicTabs.defaultOptions = {
        "speed": 300,
        "param": "tab"
    };

$.fn.organicTabs = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        (new $.organicTabs(this, options));
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the source of the first link you provided, you will see that the tabs contain links like this:

```
<a href="#featured" class="">Featured</a>
```

That's an in-page link. You should use #'s for in page links. The reason the whole url is being replaced is because it's interpreting the href as a new url to go to. #'s look inside the current page.

Comment: My code uses:

    `<ul class="nav">
   <li class="nav-three"><a href="#audio">Audio</a></li>
   <li class="nav-two"><a href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
   <li class="nav-one"><a href="#pictures" class="current">Pictures</a></li>
  </ul>`

So I believe I've set it up correctly for in page links. I have "rewrite_hash_links: false" in my config.yml which may effect it but changing this means the #link becomes mydomain.com/page/#link which won't work with the tab replace code. Perhaps I need to add code in the js to keep the URL?